# Storing/restoring an object with a null prototype

Tags: javascript

How can an object created with a null prototype using `Object.create(null,{...})` be stored in a database and restored?

And, if all you are given is the stringified object, can it be parsed to a desired prototype?

`JSON.parse()` returns an object with the default prototype.

For example,

```
let nullObj = Object.create(null, {
  a: {
     value: 10,
     writable: true
  },
  b: {
     value: 'Text'
  }
});

let jsonObj = JSON.parse('{"a":10,"b":"Text"}');
```

Trying @NickParsons comment.

```js
let nullObj = Object.create(null, {
  a: {
     value: 10,
     writable: true
  },
  b: {
     value: 'Text'
  }
});


let
   storedDescriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(nullObj),
   restObj = Object.create(null, storedDescriptors);

// Should not be writable. Fails silently since not "use strict", here.
restObj.b = "New text"; 
restObj.a = 12; 
console.log(restObj); // No toString() method.
console.log(`${restObj.a} ${restObj.b}`);

/*
{}
12 Text
*/
```

Comment: There isn't a way from the JSON string alone to know what descriptors apply to what keys. Consider storing the second argument of `Object.create()` in your database rather than the object itself, or if you don't know what it is, use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(nullObj)` to get the descriptors and store, which you can later then use `Object.create(null, JSON.parse(storedDescriptors))` to recreate the object.

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you. This works in that it keeps `writable` true for `a`.  I don't think JSON.parse() is needed; at least the code failed with it and works without it, which I think is preferrable anyway because it appears to be more work to parse to a prototype and then change it to null. One weird thing is that when I first tried this in the console only, the new object printed with a full prototype; but that doesn't happen, here.

Comment: No worries, `JSON.parse()` would only be needed if you stringified `storedDescriptors` and stored that json string in your database, then later, when you retrieve it from your DB you would parse it back and call `JSON.parse()` on it to convert the json string back into an object (keeping in mind the stringify doesn't store non-serializable data such as functions)

Comment: @NickParsons I'm so stupid! I should've realized that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(nullObj)` is returning an object. And I'll have to do exaclty as you wrote. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the base object created by [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and the object parsed from the JSON string.

You can also set the prototype of the parsed object using [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

Here's a demonstration of both approaches:

```js
const o1 = Object.create(null, {
  a: {
    value: 10,
    writable: true,
  },
  b: {
    value: "Text",
  },
});

const json = '{"a":10,"b":"Text"}';

const o2 = JSON.parse(json);

const o3 = Object.assign(
  Object.create(null),
  JSON.parse(json),
);

const o4 = JSON.parse(json);
Object.setPrototypeOf(o4, null);

console.log("o1", Object.getPrototypeOf(o1) === null); // true
console.log("o2", Object.getPrototypeOf(o2) === Object.prototype); // true
console.log("o3", Object.getPrototypeOf(o3) === null); // true
console.log("o4", Object.getPrototypeOf(o4) === null); // true
```

Comment: Thank you. I know that my question did not specifically ask about this, but is it correct that your example should not preserve any settings in `nullObj` such as `writable: true` on `a` and will always be the default of `false` on the three properties?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634110/storing-restoring-an-object-with-a-null-prototype/77634162?noredirect=1#comment136865699_77634162) @Gary The values of the `configurable`, `enumerable`, and `writable` [property descriptor attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) are `true` by default for every property of an object parsed by [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.stringify/parse with replacer/reviver to write property descriptors into JSON. We can also compress JSON by omitting defaults:

```js
const nullObj = Object.create(null, {
  a: {
     value: 10,
     writable: true
  },
  b: {
     value: 'Text'
  },
  c: {
    value: null,
    enumerable: true
  }
});


const serialize = obj => JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
  
  if(value && Object.getPrototypeOf(value) === null ){
    const props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(value);
    const defaults = new Set(['enumerable', 'configurable', 'writable']);
    Object.values(props).forEach(prop => Object.keys(prop).forEach(key => defaults.has(key) && prop[key] === false && delete prop[key])); 
    return {__$ownProps: props };
  }
  return value;
  
});

const unserialize = obj => JSON.parse(obj, (key, value) => value?.__$ownProps ? Object.create(null, value.__$ownProps) : value);

const stored = serialize(nullObj);

console.log(stored);

const restored = unserialize(stored);
restored.b = 'New text';

console.log(restored);
console.log(restored.b);
```

Answer (score -1):

to be able to store and restore an object created by `Object.create(null,{...})` you would have to use `[JSON.stringify()]`
the code would look like this

```
   // Storing
   const objWithNullPrototype = Object.create(null);
   objWithNullPrototype.property1 = 'value1';
   objWithNullPrototype.property2 = 'value2';

   const jsonString = JSON.stringify(objWithNullPrototype);

   // Restoring
   const restoredObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

   console.log(restoredObject.property1); // 'value1'
   console.log(restoredObject.property2); // 'value2'
```